# How to use (add) Row created callback in Javascript sourced data

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

I have created a table with jquery.dataTable :

```
var dataSet = [
    [ "Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800" ],
    [ "Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750" ],
    [ "Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000" ],
    [ "Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060" ],
    [ "Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700" ],
    [ "Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675" ]
];

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
        data: dataSet,
        columns: [
            { title: "Name" },
            { title: "Position" },
            { title: "Office" },
            { title: "Extn." },
            { title: "Start date" },
            { title: "Salary" }
        ]
    } );
} );
```

I want to use Row created callback to highlight the salary more than $150000. How can I do this?

Comment: parse out the `$` and `,` and convert to number within the callback and add class if it is greater. *"How can I do this"* is a bit of a broad question so it's not clear what specific problem you have doing it since you already know about the callback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code:

First, replace `,` and the symbol `$` for parse to float value.
Second compare the result and add tag `<b>`.

```
$('#example').DataTable( {
    data: dataSet,
    columns: [
        { title: "Name" },
        { title: "Position" },
        { title: "Office" },
        { title: "Extn." },
        { title: "Start date" },
        { title: "Salary",
        "render": function ( data, type, row ) {
                var salary;
                salary = parseFloat(data.replace(',','').replace('$','')); 
                console.log(salary);
                if (salary > 150000){
                   return "<b>" + data + "</b>";
                }else{
                   return data;
                }

            },
         }
    ],

} );
```

Result: https://jsfiddle.net/cmedina/7kfmyw6x/52/

Answer (score 1):

Another alternative (though @CMedina's approach works) is to use a [`rowCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/rowCallback) which will allow you to alter the whole row and highlight it. Like this:

```
"rowCallback": function(row, data, index){
    if(numeral().unformat(data[5]) > 150000){
        $(row).addClass("highlight");
        $('td:eq(5)', row).html("<b>" + data[5] + "</b>");
    }
}
```

I've included [numeral.js](http://numeraljs.com/) to make the parsing easier. Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/aghLot2n/).